# How to expand set of fonts for mathkernel.exe?

Tags: front-end

If I am running standard Mathematica and I am choosing from the menu Format->Font, I've got everything I need. All necessary scripts are present (Western, Central European,etc.). Whereas If I run mathkernel.exe and I am choosing Edit->Set Font, I've got only "Western" script. I would like to change it and have this same state like in main application Mathemathica.exe. Does anybody know how to do it?